# Issue while converting Set to Map

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

I am trying to convert Set to Map using java 8 using collectors.

```
Set<B2BUnitModel> payersList = ..... 
final Map<B2BUnitModel, List<B2BUnitPartnershipModel>> b2bUnitPartnershipMap = new HashMap<>();
final Map<B2BUnitModel, Object> map = payersList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Arrays::asList));
b2bUnitPartnershipMap.putAll(map); // Will throw Type Cast Error
```

I am not able to understand how do I convert Map values to B2BUnitPartnershipModel type since `Arrays::asList` only will return `Object` type.

Is there any way I can write something in `Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Arrays::asList)` itself so that the api will return the desired Map (`Map<B2BUnitModel, List<B2BUnitPartnershipModel>>` instead of `Map<B2BUnitModel, Object>`).

I want to create a Map with Set value as a key and empty `B2BUnitPartnershipModel` list.

Comment: don't understand how `asList` can convert `B2BUnitModel` into `List<B2BUnitPartnershipModel>`

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Show as `B2BUnitModel` and `B2BUnitPartnershipModel`.

Comment: Ok got it so is there any way i can create new empty ArrayList with B2BUnitPartnershipModel  type ?

Comment: @Divers : Do i need to only create Map by making a for loop on `payersList ` ? `B2BUnitModel ` and `B2BUnitPartnershipModel` are no where interrelated with each other. They are separate entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asuming `B2BUnitModel` is `Key` and `B2BUnitPartnershipModel` is `Value` the following code produces a map with keys from the set and empty lists as values using [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) instead of [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

#### Code

```
@Test
public void testMapCollector() {

    Set<Key> keySet = new HashSet<>();
    keySet.add(new Key("key1"));
    keySet.add(new Key("key2"));
    keySet.add(new Key("key3"));

    Map<Key, List<Value>> map = keySet.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(k -> k, key -> new ArrayList<>()));

    System.out.println(map);

}

class Key {
    String key;

    public Key(String value) {
        this.key = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Key [key=" + key + "]";
    }
}

class Value {
}
```

#### Output

```
{Key [key=key1]=[], Key [key=key3]=[], Key [key=key2]=[]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Arrays::asList` causes problem. Try this:

```
Map<B2BUnitModel, List<B2BUnitPartnershipModel>> map = set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), unit -> new ArrayList<>()));
```

Comment: there is no need to spell the full body, just `unit -> new ArrayList<>()` is enough